# asp.net in item template of list view server side checkbox not getting value on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms, itemtemplate

there is a html input type server side checkbox in item template of listview.
When I do iterate through listView.Items it finds the checkbox control but unable to determine the value whether its true or false in my case it is always false. At same location there is a label and im getting its value in listview.items iteration

here is client side code

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="LVtransferSelect_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chkTransferSelect" runat="server" class="chkTransfer" />

    <asp:Label ID="lbl_id" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>

<EmptyDataTemplate>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div class="serviceSelCont">
        <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

here is the server side code

```
foreach (ListViewDataItem item in LVtransferSelect.Items)
{
                    Label lbl_id = item.FindControl("lbl_id") as Label;
                    HtmlInputCheckBox chkTransferSelect = item.FindControl("chkTransferSelect") as HtmlInputCheckBox; 
                    if (!chkTransferSelect.Checked) continue;
}
```

Any solution ?? ..

Comment: Did you wrap the binding of the ListView inside a `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { }` check?

Comment: @VDWWD yes i have checked it .. not rebinding from anywhere so value is not resetting from anywhere

Comment: Value is true on client side but in listview.items it is always false